# C#: Caliburn Micro: How do I control the properties of a WPF Button using data binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

When a user presses a button, I'd like that button to disappear and be replaced by a Confirm button. The code below is what I thought would make the button disappear, but when I click the button, nothing happens. The DeleteButton() method is properly wired to the XAML using Caliburn Micro conventions. How can I control the button's visibility, or any other property, from the ViewModel? Thanks.

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Visibility="{Binding DeleteButtonVisibility}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
    bool _deleteButtonVisibility = true;

    public bool DeleteButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return _deleteButtonVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _deleteButtonVisibility = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DeleteButtonVisibility);
        }
    }

    public void DeleteButton()
    {
        DeleteButtonVisibility = false;
    }
```

Comment: Your binding seems fine, except for the particular case of `Visibility` always requires a converter from bool to Visibility enum, but for other properties, this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibility isn't boolean, it's `System.Windows.Visibility`

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.visibility?view=netcore-3.1

Try this:

```cs
    Visibility _deleteButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

    public Visibility DeleteButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return _deleteButtonVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _deleteButtonVisibility = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DeleteButtonVisibility);
        }
    }

    public void DeleteButton()
    {
        DeleteButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I was going to use Visibility.Hidden. Is there a good reason to use Visibility.Collapsed? What's the difference?

Comment: You can see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility?view=netcore-3.1. Essentially Collapsed means that other components can be drawn over the hidden button instead of reserving the space in the view. Hidden will just display a blank area where the hidden button is. As you intended on replacing the button, Collapsed seemed like the better fit.